# Pluralization in Angular i18next

Tags: angular, internationalization, i18next, angular12, angular-i18n

I am trying to display the no. of devices on the page using i18next.
The goal is to show the following text depending on the number of devices:

```
if count = 0   | "vCenters"
if count = 1   | "1 vCenter"
if count n > 1 | "n vCenters"
```

I followed the following link for reference, but it didn't work for me.

https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/context#combining-with-plurals

**bundle.json file**

```
  "device_vcenter_zero": "vCenter",
  "device_vcenter_one": "1 vCenter",
  "device_vcenters_other": "{{count}} vCenters",
```

**Ts File**

```
    console.log(i18next.t('device', {context: 'vcenter', count: 0}));
    console.log(i18next.t('device', {context: 'vcenter', count: 1}));
    console.log(i18next.t('device', {context: 'vcenters', count: 2}));
```

I am getting the following error in the concole.

```
i18next::translator: missingKey en-US translation device device
i18next::translator: missingKey en-US translation device device
i18next::translator: missingKey en-US translation device device
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like your language JSON file has some problem. Please check this link https://www.i18next.com/misc/json-format#i-18-next-json-v4

Comment: Check the debug logs, what is logged beside the missingKey messages?